# file manager - reading content of a folder

Tags: php, file-io

I have one issue, reading the files from a folder (in this case called 'upload'):

This is the script:

```
<div id="content">

        <?php
             echo "<h2> These is the list of the files: </h2>";

             $dir = dir("upload");

             while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {

                echo "<p>File name: " . $file . "</p>";
              }


              $dir->close();
          ?>
</div>
```

And this the result:

```
These is the list of the files:

File name: .

File name: ..

File name: prova.txt

File name: prova2.txt

File name: prova3.txt

File name: prova4.txt
```

It works, since is reading the content from the folder.
But how can i avoid to display the first two lines?
What are that two lines? Why are they displayed?

Comment: `.` => this current folder; `..` => parent folder

Comment: `&& $file[0] != '.'` <-- also no hidden files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) 
{
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {
        echo "<p>File name: " . $file . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I just join this community recently i am really surprised how much is efficient and fast!!
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition:

`if($file === "." || $file === "..") continue;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$path = '/your/path';
$results = scandir($path);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) {
        echo $result;
    }elseif (is_file($path . '/' . $result)) {
        echo  $result ;
    }
}

?>
```

You would use this method if you where going to apply one style to file and another style to a folder